# UITableViewCell delete button not disappearing

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm using a `UISegmentedControl` to switch a `UITableView` between two datasets (think favorites and recents).  Tapping the segmented control reloads the tableview with the different data set.

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:anim];
```

When the user swipes to delete a row it works fine. **HOWEVER** when the user switches datasets via the segmented control, the DELETED CELL gets re-used without altering it's appearance (i.e. the red 'DELETE' button is still there and the row content is nowhere to be seen).  This appears to be the opposite problem that most people are seeing which is the delete button not appearing.

This is the delete code:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        if ([self.current isEqualTo:self.favorites])
        {
            Favorite *fav = self.favorites[indexPath.row];

            NSMutableArray *mut = [self.favorites mutableCopy];
            [mut removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.favorites = mut;
            self.current = self.favorites;
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
    }

}
```

The tableview is set to single select, and `self.tableView.editing == NO`.  I have also tried using `[self.tableView reloadData]` and deleting/inserting the difference in rows from one dataset to the next.  Neither works.

The `UITableViewCell` I'm using supplies no `backgroundView` or `selectedBackgroundView`

---

[EDIT]

Segmented Control Value Changed:

```
- (IBAction)modeChanged:(id)sender
{
    if (self.listMode.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
         self.current = self.favorites;
    }
    else 
    {
        self.current = self.recents;
    }
    // Tryin this:
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    // Tried this:
    // [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

// Only 1 Section per table
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return [self.current count];
}
```

Comment: Update your question to include the code you have for handling the change in the segmented control and reloading the table.

Comment: @rmaddy I've added the code - it's relatively simple.

Comment: Try calling `self.editing = NO` just before calling `reloadData`

Comment: `self.editing` isn't ever changed... it's always `NO`

Comment: Is this a `UITableViewController`? Is `self.editing` isn't set then check `self.tableView.editing`.

Comment: That still doesn't work.  `self.editing` or `self.tableView.editing`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Oh for the love of...

I wasn't calling `[super prepareForReuse];` in my `UITableViewCell` subclass.

UGH.

Comment: I've got what sounds like a very similar problem... but I haven't overridden prepareForReuse, and in fact I'm specifying nil for my reuseIdentifier, so according to the docs, it wouldn't get called anyway.

Comment: Aha -- this was on the right track.  But I'll post my finding as a separate answer, for clarity.

Comment: Exactly my issue. Thanks for saving some hairs on my head!

Comment: Bang on for me. I omitted my call to super. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing: to "delete" a custom UITableViewCell, I was removing it from the table and putting it onto another list, which the user could then display in a modal view when they have regrets and want to put it back.  In iOS7 (but not iOS6), the cells so moved had the big ugly "DELETE" button still on them, despite calling setEditing:NO and so on.  (And in addition, the rest of the cell content was not drawn at all, even though inspecting the cells in the debugger showed that all the subpanes were still there.)

Unlike Stephen above, I hadn't overridden prepareForReuse, so that wasn't the problem.  But it was related: in my case, the cells weren't created with a reuse identifier:

```
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

And per the docs, "If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called."  But apparently, in iOS7 at least, it *should* be.

So the solution, in my case, was to explicitly call this [cell prepareForReuse] on each cell as I loaded it into the new table.